# Java CometD Jetty protocol equivalent in javascript

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, websocket, cometd

```
    webSocketClient = new WebSocketClient();
    webSocketClient.start();
    wsTransport = new JettyWebSocketTransport(null, null, webSocketClient);
    bayeuxClient = new BayeuxClient(url, wsTransport);
    bayeuxClient.getChannel(someChannel);
    bayeauxClient.handshake(handshakeAuthRequest);
```

Considering the above Java code works (and everything had been declared), how can I specify the Jetty *ClientTransport* *wsTransport* in Javascript (node.js)?

I have tried something along the lines of:

```
var connection = new comet.CometD();
connection.configure({
    url: url,
    channel: someChannel
}

connection.handshake(handshakeAuthRequest, function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

But I get an Unknown Bayeaux Transport reason for failure, probably because I have no Jetty transport protocol specified anywhere, nor can I find how to do it for javascript. Part of the response below.

```
 {
  id: '1',
  successful: false,
  channel: '/meta/handshake',
  failure: {
    reason: 'Unknown Bayeux Transport',
    exception: undefined,
    httpCode: 400,
    connectionType: 'long-polling',
 ......
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The short answer** is that you can define the websocket protocol by calling `yourCometDObject.registerTransport('websocket', new comet.WebSocketTransport())`

**The Long answer for my case and node.js**
I'll start by stating an important bits of information.
Keep in mind that I am in a **node.js** project.

In the *cometd.js* file from the `cometd` repo, instantiating the **CometD** object calls this block adding the *websocket* protocol:

```
if (window.WebSocket) {
        this.registerTransport('websocket', new WebSocketTransport());
}
```

And here are the caveats.

1. *Node.js* does not have a *window* object (makes sense, since it's thought as a back-end framework first).
2. There is a `cometd-nodejs-client` library, but it does **not** support the *websocket* protocol, as stated on their github page. As such, there is not way to add it later with `registerTransport('websocket', new WebSocketTransport())`, since WebSocketTransport is not defined in that library.

In order to use *websocket* in `node.js` **with** `cometd`, you have to install the `browser-env` package and use it like this: `require('browser-env)();`in your module. This will bypass the *window* object not existing part.

After that, it becomes a simple matter of getting the code I posted here and adding what's missing.

```
var connection = new comet.CometD();
var transport = new comet.WebSocketTransport();
connection.registerTransport('websocket', transport);
connection.unregisterTransport('callback-polling');
connection.unregisterTransport('long-polling');
connection.configure({
    url: url,
    channel: someChannel
}

connection.handshake(handshakeAuthRequest, function (response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Notice I've also removed the *long-polling* and *callback-polling* protocols. You can also specify an index 0 for the websocket protocol, in case you want it to be the default, like:

```
connection.registerTransport('websocket', transport, 0);
```

Comment: `cometd-nodejs-client` supports WebSocket since version 1.1.0, so you don't need to do anything you describe in this answer. Just do as explained in the README for the `cometd-nodejs-client` project.

Answer (score 1):

If the server works with the Java client, then it should work with the JavaScript client too.

CometD has a browser-JavaScript client library that is shipped with the main CometD project and also present [here](https://github.com/cometd/cometd-javascript).

There is also nodejs-JavaScript client library, which is a tiny wrapper around the browser-JavaScript library, [here](https://github.com/cometd/cometd-nodejs-client), and it's deployed as a NPM package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cometd-nodejs-client).

The error "Unknown Bayeux Transport" is typically due to the fact that the server does not support WebSocket, or it is incorrectly configured, so make sure it works with the Java client first if it's easier for you, and then use the NodeJS client.

Comment: that's the library I'd been using. In the end, it WAS an issue of the node version not having websocket, and the javascript comet lib needing a window object.